# How to pass the array to @input(), to another @input() of different component?

Tags: angular

I was able to pass my array to first @Input(); and displayed the contents of my array. Now, the problem is, I want to pass the data of the first @Input() to my second @Input(); then display it. Kind of new to angular and I'm learning how to pass data.

Comment: Before going further read angular documentation for component interaction.https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass it the same way how you passed it from parent to child component.

**Parent component**

```html
<app-child [customInput]="input></app-child>
```

**Child component**

Controller

```js
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() customInput: any;
  .
  .
}
```

Template

```html
<app-grandchild [customInput]="customInput"></app-grandchild>
```

**Grand child**

Controller

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectionRef } from '@angular/core';

export class GrandChildComponent {
  @Input() customInput: any;
  .
  .
}
```